# Magento errors while installing using Wamp server

Tags: magento2

I got the below error while installing the Magento 2.3.5 in windows 10 PC using Wamp server.

```
Module 'Magento_Theme':
[ERROR] InvalidArgumentException: Wrong file in C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php:64 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(55): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->open('C:/wamp64/www/m...') #1 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(36): Magento\Framework\Image->open() #2 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\Image->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2), 'C:/wamp64/www/m...') #3 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #4 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #5 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Factory.php(47): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #6 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Design\Theme\Image.php(127): Magento\Framework\Image\Factory->create('C:/wamp64/www/m...') #7 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(135): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\Image->createPreviewImage('C:/wamp64/www/m...') #8 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(114): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_savePreviewImage(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data)) #9 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(73): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_registerThemeRecursively(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data)) #10 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\module-theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes.php(47): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->register() #11 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier.php(162): Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes->apply() #12 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1023): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch('Magento_Theme') #13 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(890): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array) #14 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array) #15 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(371): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #16 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #17 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #18 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #19 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #20 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(115): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #21 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(117): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #22 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321): Laminas\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #23 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #24 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Application.php(339): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #25 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\index.php(39): Laminas\Mvc\Application->run() #26 {main} Next Magento\Framework\Setup\Exception: Unable to apply data patch Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes for module Magento_Theme. Original exception message: Wrong file in C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier.php:170 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1023): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch('Magento_Theme') #1 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(890): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array) #2 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array) #3 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(371): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #5 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #6 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #7 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #8 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(115): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #9 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(117): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #10 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321): Laminas\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #11 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #12 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Application.php(339): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #13 C:\wamp64\www\magento-ce-2.3.5-p1-2020-04-24-08-33-34_2\setup\index.php(39): Laminas\Mvc\Application->run() #14 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved following this manual:  [[ERROR] InvalidArgumentException](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311897/error-incomplete-installation)

Find validateURLScheme function in vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php file at line 96. Replace function with this:

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
{
  $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
  $url = parse_url($filename);
  if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Above solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem while installing 2.3.5 using Wamp on Windows 10. The error occurred while the installer tried to install "Module 'Magento_Theme'".

### Workaround

I worked around the problem by installing version 2.3.4 instead of 2.3.5. To do this:

- Delete the existing database and create a new empty database
- Delete the content of C:\wamp64\www\
- Go to the download archive tab in the Download page of Magento
- Download 2.3.4 and unzip it to C:\wamp64\www\
- Go to http://localhost *in Incognito mode*. As the installer otherwise remembers your 2.3.5 settings and fails, as it tries to install 2.3.5 sample data module.