# Error Incomplete installation

Tags: magento2.3, installation, exception, localhost, vendor

I'm a beginner and trying to install Magento 2.3.5 on my localhost.
I've tried several times but at a point 51% get the following error message:

> [ERROR] InvalidArgumentException: Wrong file in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php:64
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(55):
> Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->open('C:/xampp/htdocs...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(36):
> Magento\Framework\Image->open() #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(121):
> Magento\Framework\Image->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2),
> 'C:/xampp/htdocs...') #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewo...',
> Array) #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(56):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...',
> Array) #5
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Factory.php(47):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewo...',
> Array) #6
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\View\Design\Theme\Image.php(127):
> Magento\Framework\Image\Factory->create('C:/xampp/htdocs...') #7
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(135):
> Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\Image->createPreviewImage('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
>
> ## 8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(114):
>
> Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_savePreviewImage(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data))
>
> ## 9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(73):
>
> Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_registerThemeRecursively(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data))
>
> ## 10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\module-theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes.php(47):
>
> Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->register() #11
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier.php(162):
> Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes->apply() #12
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1023):
> Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch('Magento_Theme')
>
> ## 13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(890):
>
> Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup),
> 'data', Array) #14 [internal function]:
> Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array) #15
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(371):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #16
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109):
> Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #17
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83):
> Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #18
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321):
> Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> ## 19 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178):
>
> Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent),
> Object(Closure)) #20
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(117):
> Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure),
> Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #21
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(117):
> Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request),
> Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #22
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321):
> Laminas\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> ## 23 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178):
>
> Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent),
> Object(Closure)) #24
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Application.php(339):
> Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure),
> Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #25
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\index.php(39):
> Laminas\Mvc\Application->run() #26 {main} Next
> Magento\Framework\Setup\Exception: Unable to apply data patch
> Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes for module
> Magento_Theme. Original exception message: Wrong file in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier.php:170
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1023):
> Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch('Magento_Theme')
>
> ## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(890):
>
> Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup),
> 'data', Array) #2 [internal function]:
> Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array) #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(371):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109):
> Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #5
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83):
> Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #6
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321):
> Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> ## 7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178):
>
> Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent),
> Object(Closure)) #8
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(117):
> Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure),
> Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #9
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(117):
> Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request),
> Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #10
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321):
> Laminas\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> ## 11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178):
>
> Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent),
> Object(Closure)) #12
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Application.php(339):
> Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure),
> Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #13
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mattkompaniet\setup\index.php(39):
> Laminas\Mvc\Application->run() #14 {main}

What do I wrong getting this error? As said I'm a beginner, please advise.
Brgds Hseb

Comment: you can change url to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 6):

This is very common in localhost installations. Follow the below to fix the issue Find validateURLScheme function in below file

> vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php file

at line 96. Replace function with this:

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
{
      $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
      $url = parse_url($filename);
      if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks it works..

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal Happy Coding. Please mark as correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all cache and Try to use incognito web browser.

Comment: I've cleared the cache, using icognito browser, changed setting in PHP:ini but still the installation stops at 51% with last row magento_theme.
I'm using xampp, php version 7.1.11 on windows 10 home edition, first time to install magento with no previous project installed on pc. 
Downloaded both magento 2.3.5 p1 with samples and without samples. Could not open the zip file version and downloaded tar.gz version and extracted under xampp/htdocs/ folder.
Is there any other ways to get around or identify the root cause causing the installation stops at this certain point.