# Magento installation stuck at 51%

Tags: magento2.3, installation

I am installing Magento and it gets stuck here, I followed all instructions online but I get stuck here. It does not give me error on the console log but it get stuck here for over an hour. Can someone please assist me?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Check log what is the exact error?

Comment: Please refer the link.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311897/error-incomplete-installation/311898#311898

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1**
Open the file and change replace **validateURLScheme** Method

**vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php**

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
    {
      $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
      $url = parse_url($filename);
      if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

**when you replace that method and retry the installation.**

**Step -2**

if you face admin going to black than please chnage method **isPathInDirectories** in file
**\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php**

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**

Answer (score 0):

Not only the above function will help you for all. In my case there was php.ini extensions what I was missing. You need to enable few extensions as well and then these function. [read here](https://webarchers.com/installing-magento-2-on-xampp-got-stuck-at-51/)